# dateformatter problem?

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I want to change the date formats. But i don't know how to give the input format

`Thu, 2 Dec 2010 00:28:56 -0500' i use the date formatter for user custom format

```
   NSString *inputString = @"Thu, 2 Dec 2010 00:28:56 -0500";
   NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];

   NSDate *inputDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:inputString];
   NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE. MMM. d, yyyy"];

   NSString *outputDate = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:inputDate];
   mylabel.text = outputDate;
```

but date not display

please give me the solution

Comment: First, you should check (and tell us) which of the 2 operations fail: `dateFromString:` or `stringFromDate:`? What locale is your device set to? The code you quoted will not work in a locale other than English. (It may not work with an English locale, either, I haven't checked the format string thoroughly.)

Comment: @Ole Begemann-the inputDate not set....

Comment: Why did you remove the format string you had? It is correct.

Comment: @Ole Begemann- no its wrong i need that only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format string you showed us before you edited your question was correct. The only thing that was missing was that you need to set the date formatter's locale to English if you want it to recognize English month and day names:

```
[inputFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
```

Comment: setLocale is works perfectly thanks but @"en_US" is set the local language. i want to show the language in english

Comment: Huh? (PS: you should re-edit your question and add the format string you removed)

Comment: What else is there to check out? I already told you the format string is correct, you just need to set the locale.